# Regex do not include 666 and 900-999

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to use regex to check if a number is valid but I'm getting an error and not sure how to write this.

```
regex e{R"(((^666)|(^900-999))(-*)([^0-6])(-*)(\d{4}))"};
```

So what I'm trying to say is "check for: a number that is not 666 or from 900-999 then an optional hyphen, a number from 0-6 and an optional hyphen, then 4 digits.

I tried running this but no matter what I put, the console tells me that my input is always incorrect.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "900-999" represents a quantity range and regex work on character patterns.  In general, you should consider decomposing your pattern to see which parts work and which don't.  Does "`(^666)`" refer to "a number that is not 666"?  Probably not, it probably refers to "a character that is not `6` followed by two `6` characters.

Comment: @BrianCain No, `^666` refers to the string "666" appearing at the beginning of a string. `^` only inverts character sets (e.g, `[^a-z]`).

Comment: @duskwuff - Ok, good point.  So I'll go back to decomposing the pattern.  Let's see if we can match "a number that is not '666'": must the number have three digits exactly?  ...at most three digits?

Comment: What happens if the number before the hyphen is less than 100? Is that permitted? Is 001-0-1234 supposed to be a valid input? What about 1-0-1234? Or (without the hyphens) 101234?

Comment: And `-*` matches an optional *sequence* of dashes, not just an optional dash. You probably wanted `-?`.

Comment: Yeah the number has to have three digits. I tried doing [^666-666] but that wouldnt work either. Is there way to put in an "and" instead of the "|"?

Comment: Yes it has to be able to have a three digit number in the beginning even if it is 001

Comment: It's not clear to me what number you actually want to allow.

Comment: Are you trying to match a US [Social Security number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number)? The format you're describing sounds a lot like that.

Comment: Yes I need to do it for a project. Your answer helped me a lot. So far I have this     regex e{R"((((?!000)(?!666)(?!9\d{2})\d{3}))((-*)(?!00)\d{2})((-*)(?!0000)\d{4})"};  which has done well for the first two entries but when i set in the (?!0000)\d{4} I get an error

Comment: I forgot that I needed to make sure none of the entries set in were all zeros.

Comment: I got it to work. Thanks for all of the help guys.

Comment: @AAA The format you're describing in the question is not quite correct for a SSN. The middle section is two digits, not one (e.g, 123-45-6789).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a task that regular expressions are well suited for.

If you want to check for a number that isn't equal to 666 or in the range 900-999, you need to decompose that into the following ugly set of cases:

- A digit that isn't 6 or 9, followed by two more digits
- 6 followed by a digit that isn't 6, then one more digit
- 66 followed by one more digit that isn't 6

As a regular expression, that'd be (with some spaces added for clarity):

```
(
    [0-578][0-9][0-9]
    |
    6[0-57-9][0-9]
    |
    66[0-57-9]
)
```

As you can see, this isn't a reasonable way to go about this. Reserve the regular expression for checking the format, then check logical issues (like "can't be 666 or 900-999") separately, in code. As a bonus, this will allow you to give precise error messages for these logical issues, instead of lumping them under a generic "wrong format" error.

Comment: so in the block [0-578] its not saying zero to five hundred and seventy eight but zero, five, seven, and eight?

Comment: If the regex supports it, a negative lookahead will still *work*. For example, all three digit numbers that are not in the 900s or 666: `(?!666)(?!9\d{2})\d{3}`

Comment: @AAA Correct. A character group (anything in square brackets) matches a single character; the stuff in the brackets defines what characters will be matched.

Comment: @chris That's an excellent point. Mind writing that up as another answer? Be clear that it will only work with PCRE or compatible.

Answer (score 1):

What you want, if you decide to do this with only regular expressions, is a *negative lookahead*. However, this is not part of some regular expression specifications. Within C++, the only compatible syntax option is `std::regex_constants::ECMAScript`, which happens to be the default when constructing a `std::regex`.

The negative lookahead is represented by `(?!<expr>)`, where there will be no match if `<expr>` matches at that point. For example, `(?!666)` would disallow the literal string "666" from being present at that point in the matching.

We can use this to fix your original regular expression. Note that I put in some non-exhaustive [tests](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a3cc3bc0bdaec88) for this as well.

```
std::regex e{R"((?!666|9\d{2})\d+-?[0-6]-?\d{4})"};
```

Let's decompose this:

`(?!666|9\d{2})` - We have a negative lookahead that prevents this from matching when 666 or a three-digit number starting with 9 appears at the beginning.

`\d+` - Here is the number we are matching that cannot be 666 or in the 900s. I chose to match any number of digits here because the question didn't specify otherwise.

`?-` - An optional hyphen. Your question contains `-*`, which is zero or more hyphens.

`[0-6]` - A single digit from 0 to 6. Your question has a leading caret, which has the effect of negating the character set. This would allow any character except for 0-6.

`-?` - Another optional hyphen.

`\d{4}` - A four-digit number.